# Will a 96W charger harm a 2023 MacBook Pro's battery faster?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

As opposed to a 67W charging brick. Will the battery health drop faster?

Comment: Power is not pushed into the Mac by the charger; the Mac draws the power it needs. The rating is a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. And the long answer is also no.

Comment: So many answers already on here cover how the chargers work and control the charging regime.